# UITableView selection issue in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller, tableview

I found several questions similar to mine but maybe not related to the same problem.
I'm using `swift` for my code and I noticed a problem using `tableView`.
I want to implement cell selection using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.
That method works perfectly if you create a `UITableViewController` class from scratch.
On the contrary using `UIViewController` with a `tableView` using proper delegates `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` the same method does not work.

I don't know what am I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:
The cell selection is implemented as

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("selected")
  }
```

adding the `override` in the `UITableViewController` class

my main `ViewController` has the following protocols

```
ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { 
    // my code here .... 
}
```

Comment: Did you set the tableview's delegate/datasource property to `self`?

Comment: It's hard to guess without knowing what your code does.

Comment: @Mike where should I put the self?

Comment: @PhillipMills the code is quite standard, I think...

Comment: Exactly same my own code works perfect. And could you please provide links to the same issues about which you are talking? Here is no error unless you haven't connect `delegate`

Comment: @Azat no errors in my Xcode...everything runs smoothly except the cell selection

Comment: When you create your UITableViewController, you need to set `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableview.dataSource = self`.

Comment: Maybe you have edited in `xib` the `selection` property of  `tableView` or `tableViewCell`?

Comment: have you tried reading a tutorial for table view in swift maybe?...

Comment: @Azat you were right, the delegate was missing in the storyboard. I added the delegate and it worked. I don't know why adding the delegate in the .swift file wasn't enough

Comment: When you added the delegate in the .swift file, what did your code for that look like?  (If you mean just declaring the protocol, that's not the same as assigning the delegate.)

Comment: @Nicholas adding the delegate in the .swift file could not be enough if you haven't connect `IBOutlet` to `tableView` as well

Comment: @Azat The IBOutlet's been already set, since I configured custom cells and other methods. The strange thing is that I could set almost every method of the tableView except the cell selection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has no errors. Make sure you have connected `delegate` from the `xib` or `storyboard` or from code and check maybe you have edited in `xib` the `selection` property of `tableView` or `tableViewCell`

Comment: using the same code I just connected as a delegate the tableView in the UIViewController. Of course, thank you very much.